# Preview Excel file in browser - Blob data

Tags: angular

I am trying to get blob and  preview the file in browser, it works fine for pdf files. How can i preview the excel files, when trying to preview excel it is downloading the file (looking for a java script, HTML solution)

Answer (score 0):

You can use xlsx npm package to read Excel files.
I have created stackblitz https://angular-kpvq2i.stackblitz.io

You can find more details on https://www.npmjs.com/package/xlsx

Comment: Thanks for the response , But this will read the excel file and display in the browser. Is there any way to just open excel in browser like PDF file. I am getting BLOB data from back end server and i am trying to open in new browser tab.